# Internal working of static and non-static forward references in Java

Tags: java, static, non-static, forward-reference

I am working with forward references in Java and wondering why Java allows forward reference with either `ClassName` (in static variable) or with `this` reference in case of instance variable? What is the **background process** that is taking place **at the level of JVM?** For instance:

**Static Forward Reference-**

```
class StaticForwardReferences {
    static {
        sf1 = 10;   // (1)
        int b = sf1 = 20;   // (2)
        int c = StaticForwardReferences.sf1; // (3) Works fine
        // Above statement allows the allocation of value of 'sf1'
        // to variable 'c' just because it is accessed with class name
        // instead of direct name

        // whereas below statement throws illegal forward reference
        // error at compile time
        System.out.println(sf1); // (4) Illegal forward reference
    }
    static int sf1 = sf2 = 30;
    static int sf2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Is there any kind of temporary storage where the values get stored when we do a forward reference by assigning the variables before their declaration as done in (1) and (2) steps above, if we print the value of variable `c`, it shows the value from the most recent assignment did to `sf1`.

**Non-static Forward Reference-**

```
class NonStaticForwardReferences {
    {
        nsf1 = 10;
        System.out.println(this.nsf1);  // 10
        nsf1 = sf1;
        // System.out.println(nsf1); Illegal forward reference
        int b = nsf1 = 20;

        int c = this.nsf1;
        System.out.println(c);  // 20
        // why variable 'c' is initialized to 20 when used with 'this' reference
        // instead of showing illegal forward reference, how it works in the background?
   }

   int nsf1 = nsf2 = 30;
   int nsf2;
   static int sf1 = 5;

   public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Please put some light on the **background process** that is taking place behind the scenes for the above two cases. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

The [JLS, Section 8.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3), states the conditions for making a forward reference to a static variable (a "class variable") a compiler error, although it doesn't state the reasoning.

> Use of class variables whose declarations appear textually after the use is sometimes restricted, even though these class variables are in scope (§6.3). Specifically, it is a compile-time error if all of the following are true:
>
> - The declaration of a class variable in a class or interface C appears textually after a use of the class variable;
> - The use is a *simple name* in either a class variable initializer of C or a *static initializer* of C;
> - The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;
> - C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use.

(*italic* emphasis mine)

The instance variables forward reference error appears with similar conditions:

> Use of instance variables whose declarations appear textually after the use is sometimes restricted, even though these instance variables are in scope. Specifically, it is a compile-time error if all of the following are true:
>
> - The declaration of an instance variable in a class or interface C appears textually after a use of the instance variable;
> - The use is a *simple name* in either an instance variable initializer of C or an *instance initializer* of C;
> - The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;
> - C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use.

(*italic* emphasis mine)

In both cases, using a *simple name* is the key condition here.  That means using the variable without any qualifier such as `this` or a class name.  This is why `this.nsf1` works in `NonStaticForwardReferences`.  If you remove `this`, then the error occurs.  This is also why `sf1` has the error and `StaticForwardReferences.sf1;` does not have the error.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but this is not what I asked for. I know the rules of forward reference in Java for both static and non-static cases but what I asked is the internal process that is taking place if I use the class name or 'this' reference. What happens when these two are used and why particularly we are able to achieve the situation which contradicts (in some manner) the 'declaration-before-read' rule.

Comment: The reasoning is that it’s a safety measure which makes no attempt to cover every case.

Answer (score 0):

Java    requires    that    the declaration of  a   field   must    occur   before  its usage   in  any initializer
expression  if  the field   is  used    on  the right-hand  side    of  an  assignment  in  the initializer
expression. This    essentially means   that    the declaration of  a   field   must    occur   before  the
value   of  the field   is  read    in  an  initializer expression.

When    making  forward references  using   simple  names,  code    in  a   static  initializer block   is
also    subject to  the declaration-before-reading  rule    discussed   above.

As  in  an  instance    initializer expression, the keywords    "this"  and "super" can be  used    to
refer   to  the current object  in  an  instance    initializer block.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but this is not what I asked for. I know the rules of forward reference in Java for both static and non-static cases but what I asked is the internal process that is taking place if I use the class name or 'this' reference. What happens when these two are used and why particularly we are able to achieve the situation which contradicts (in some manner) the 'declaration-before-read' rule.

Answer (score 0):

The prohibition on forward references does not imply that variables are *created* when initialized.  The “background process” is just that classes and objects are allocated all at once, with the (static) variables being given [default values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).  (Which is to say “zero”: it’s probably implemented with `calloc` or `memset` in practice.)

The forward reference rules are [meant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) to prevent seeing these first values, especially for `final` variables which supposedly ever have only one value.  But they exist to catch human error and are themselves not perfect: only for constant variables does the initialization happen [so](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2) [early](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3.1) that the default values are unobservable.  Specifying `this` or a class name explicitly is the simplest way of demonstrating this effect.